# Laravel 8 dissappear button

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to after the first guest registers that the register button dissappears, but i don't know how. I tried it this way but it didn't work.

```
@if(Auth::user()) 
                        
@else
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('register') }}</a>
   </li>
@endif
```

Comment: after the user registered, is he logged in ? cause that's the correct solution

Comment: How about `Auth::check()`

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand `public function check() {  return ! is_null($this->user()); }` so it's the same but longer.

Comment: After register, the user is authenticated,  so  the else condition won't work then.

Comment: it doesnt work :(. The moment i register it says true but after i logout it goes back to false. If this helps it is in the @guest idk if this causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

First, load all users according to your database, for example:

```
$users=DB::table('users')->get();
```

Then check the number of users, if less than 1, show register button:

```
@if(count($users)<1) 
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('register') }}</a>
   </li>
@endif
```

Comment: that isnt the problem. What i want is that after 1 person register that the register button dissappear for everyone. but idk how since these methods dont work.